# Fixed table layout, but one column adjusting to content? (HTML and CSS only)

Tags: html, css, html-table

In the snippet below, is it possible to get label column to adjust to its content? Currently it receives no width at all :(.

For this question I am only interested in possible solutions that use HTML tables and CSS, without the help of Javascript libraries.

```css
table { width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse; }

td { border: 1px solid black; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

input[type='text'] { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="width: 100%;"></td>
  <td style="width: auto;">Label:</td>
  <td style="width: 5px;"></td>
  <td style="width: 200px;"><input type='text' /></td>
  <td style="width: 100%;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Context: I am used to program desktop application grid layouts that consist of growing columns, fixed-width columns and columns that adjust to the preferred size of the content. Usually it is also possible to provide resize weights for the growing columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For layout I would suggest using awesome new css feature: [css grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). This way you have way more control over your layout, it's semantically correct, elegant and easier to maintain. With css grids you can actually do what you want so much, though using different unit (fr instead of %). Don't use table if it's content is not pure data. And if you do use table, I would suggest not messing with columns width too much to make it easier to be responsive.

[Css grids](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) are quite new feature and it's actually the first legit way of doing layout. It may be confused with older, common way of doing layout, like [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid). These are not the same and quite different! Pick any way of doing grids you like more, but definitely don't use tables for the layout. :)

Comment: Thanks. I gave you my vote, but won't accept as answer just yet, as strictly speaking it does not answer the specific question I asked. But it probably does solve my actual underlying problem, so hopefully it will help others as well.

Comment: Well, then accept the other answer, which answer your original question, but doesn't solve your real problem. ;d (this answer does the opposite)

Answer (score 2):

Well, just make sure that sum of all columns width is no more than 100%. `width: auto` sets width of whatever space is left, but there's nothing left when other columns takes >100% of width.

Try this:

```
<table class="t">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 40%;">a</td>
    <td style="width: auto;">b</td>
    <td style="width: 50px;">c</td>
    <td style="width: 40%;">d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If table width is 1000px, then 1% of width is 10px. In that case `40%` takes 400px, `50px` takes... 50px, and `auto` takes what's left, which is `(1000px - 400px - 400px - 50px) == 150px`.

If you had 2 columns with `width: auto`, then these columns width would be 75px, because 150px (space left) / 2 (number of columns `width: auto`) == 75px.

If I had 4 columns with widths: 50%, 50%, 50px, auto, then no matter how wide table is, the space left is kind of `-50px` (which is what makes `width: auto` look like `width: 0`).

Make sure your "space left" is more than 0. One column with `width: 100%` and you're out of it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the width of the label column. It should adjust to the content. Also if I don't use fixed-layout, the constant column widths are not respected.

Comment: Well, the answer is still the same. :) Don't set sum of widths > 100%. If you don't know the table width, then safest way is always use percentages so you always know you won't overflow (>100%). If you really want to set width in px for some column, then maybe it's still good idea to add `max-width: 5%` for safety when table is getting to small.

Comment: One option that may help you is to specify a min-width value for columns. But the purpose of responsive design is that it changes to adapt the content and screen size, so you can't apply the same principles as in fixed-width design. `auto` will let the browser decide the width of the column; for the rest use *either* % and let the table adapt to the display, *or*  use px to fix the width, but you can't mix them - it just doesn't make sense. A table can't be more than 100% in width, but trying to mix % and px could result in your table being > 100% as in @kamyl 's example.

Comment: @FluffyKitten of course it makes sense. In desktop apps we have tons of layouts that mix auto (content preferred size), fixed-width and growing columns.

Comment: It doesn't, as @kamyl has already explained. Its basic maths. A table with 5 columns: `| 200px | 200px | 25% | 25% | auto |`. At *width=1200px*: `| 250px | 250px | 300px (25%) | 300px (25%) | 100px (auto) |` Now, display that on a *768px display* and you get: `| 250px | 250px | 192px (25%) | 192px (25%) | ???? (auto) |` ... the first 4 cols without the auto add up to 884px which is already bigger than the table width.

Comment: Isn't it nice how programmers always tell users how what they want doesn't make sense or why it isn't possible? Anyway, try to see the percentage values as resize weights, and it starts to make a lot of sense. So in your example (200px, 200px, 25%, 25%, auto): If 1200px are available, the distribution would be 200px, 200px, half-of-remaining, half-of-remaining, content-width. Pretty straight-forward, I would think.

Comment: @Zalumon Sure, I could see how "the percentage values as resize weights" might make sense... ***but that is not how CSS works***. 25% means *literally* 25% - not "half of remaining" or "25%-ish" or "25% until we don't want it to be 25% any more" or any other non-specific value. We are bound by the rules of the language, and as much as you might wish it worked diffferently, not even computers can defy mathematics: the defined widths of the columns in a table *cannot logically add up to more than its total width*. I'd have thought that was obvious.

Comment: Oh come on. In my example, change the two "100%" widths to "500%" and "200%" (or whatever) and you can observe that they already do behave like resize weights (and add up to more than the total width).

Comment: @Zalumon It is up to the browser what it does with erroneous data. You might get lucky and some might display it the way you want, but you cannot rely on the outcome cross-platform or cross-browser so its entirely unsuitable for a professional live site. If you want to roll the dice and hope that most browsers display your data the way you would like, that's entirely up to you..... but isn't the very reason you posted here because the browser ***didn't*** behave the way you wanted when you did it that way?

Comment: It is the auto column that doesn't behave like i want it to, not the growing (percentage) ones.

Comment: @Zalumon Yes, because *your column widths cannot add up to more than the table width*. If you use erroneous data, you are going to get errors. Do you really not understand that? You asked for a solution to your problem, well that's it: use valid widths. Or put up with the consequences of the browser not knowing what to do with your illogical values and doing something unexpected. If you don't like it, I'm sorry but we can't change the rules of CSS or the laws of mathematics for you. Code by the rules of CSS or don't - your choice.

Comment: Is there a chance you confuse layout with table? For layout I would suggest using awesome new css feature: [css grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). This way you have way more control over your layout and it's semantically correct. With css grids you can actually do what you do want so much, though using different unit (fr instead of %). Don't use table if it's content is not pure data. And if you do use table, I would suggest not messing with columns width too much to make it easier to be responsive. Well, either this post is OT, or I just discovered a XY problem.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Seriously? Wow.

Comment: @kamyl I haven't heard about CSS grids yet. I will have a look.

Comment: @Zalumon Yes seriously: you have to use proper valid data in order to prevent unexpected errors from occurring. Who'd have thought it?

Comment: @Zalumon "*I haven't heard about CSS grids yet*"... Grids have been the defacto layout tool for a decade, so you obviously don't have experience in web design. In that case, its understandable you don't understand the rules of CSS & responsive design; however when you're asking for help, you should accept advice from those who *do* understand it. Arguing over facts just because you don't like them isn't going to change anything. If you're laying out non-tabular data then CSS grids are the logical choice, but be aware that they are fully % based. Try Bootstrap its one of the most commonly used.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Ouch, that hurt more than I expected. You just don't know when to stop.

Comment: @Zalumon It wasn't meant to hurt, & apologies if it did. I was just saying I now understand why you'd a different view of the problem. Its fine to be less familiar with some disciplines than others, no one has an issue with that. We're all here to both help & learn. It was also practical advice on dealing with help you're offered in such situations. Edit: In relation to CSS grids, there are grid layouts such as Bootstrap, and then there's the 2D CSS grid layout linked to by kamyl which is relatively new. Apologies if you were referring specifically to that, I assumed you meant grids in general

Comment: don't worry about me... @kamyl CSS grid looks awesome, I am going to try to switch from html tables to that. Seems like browser support is already pretty decent. Please convert to an answer.

Comment: One caveat about CSS Grids is that its still new, and while thats a good thing, the one downfall is that people are less familiar with it. I don't use Bootstrap, but a huge proportion of CSS questions here do use it, so there is an abundance of people on SO who can help if you run into issues - many people have some difficulties with grids systems after coming from table layouts. So while CSS grids are the way to go, it might be worth thinking about taking an interim step to Bootstrap on your way there first, in case you need good support. But either way, a better choice than tables.

Comment: Sure, will convert my comment into answer in a moment. And don't be mad at @FluffyKitten, he's right about lots of things here. :) It can be difficult and even annoying to deal with XY problem. But it's definitely true that width of columns can't (shouldn't) be more than table width (>100%).

Comment: @kamyl Good catch on the XY Problem. I just assume that anyone using tables is using it for tabular data. P.S. I'm a she, not a he :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like CSS grid does exactly what I was looking for:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 5px 200px 1fr;  
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px; // top + left
}

.container > DIV { 
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0; // right + bottom
}

input[type='text'] { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div>Label:</div>
  <div></div>
  <div><input type='text' /></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```